# not able to delete a table row created by jquery, the code is creating extra unnecessary columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a function to append table rows whenever a user selects values from checkbox popup window. If the user selects same or different check box values , the old values should be deleted. My code is not deleting/replacing the old row and somehow it deletes the name of the old row and creates extra table data values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktW4B.jpg
In this case, the second circled table row should have replaced the first circled row.

```
function AppendSampleTable(specimenNumberTextBoxId, specimenArray, _combinatedIdForSampleTbl) {
          // var specimenNumberTextBoxId = "MOLECULAR DIAGNOSTICSSpec1";
          var sampleTable = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblSample');
          // var sampleTable = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sampleNum6');
          var specimenType = document.getElementById(specimenNumberTextBoxId).getAttribute("specimentype");
          var poolSpecimenCode = document.getElementById(specimenNumberTextBoxId).getAttribute("poolspecimen");
          var specimenNumber = "test";
          var tableRows = $(sampleTable).find('tr');
          var rowIndex = tableRows.length;
          var i = 0;
          var newRow;
          var specimenArrayLength = specimenArray.length - 1; // Because specimenArray contains empty string for first element.

          // Erase tr that has same name as requested.
          var $oldRow = $(sampleTable).find('tr[name="' + _combinatedIdForSampleTbl + '"]'); //WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING OR IS IT? SHOUDL IT REMOVE OLD ROWS?// 3/28/2019
          alert("old row=" + $oldRow);
          $oldRow.remove();
          // Append tr that contains desired values.
          for (i; i < specimenArrayLength; i++) {
              // If none of specimen has choosen for a pool, array will contain 'undefined', so we need to ignore that not to be appended into table.
              if (specimenArray[i + 1] != undefined) {
                  specimenNumber = specimenArray[i + 1];

                  newRow = "<tr name='" + _combinatedIdForSampleTbl + "'><td class='col-xs-2'><span id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sampleName" + (rowIndex + i + 1) + "' specimenCode='" + poolSpecimenCode + "'>POOL - " + specimenType + "</span></td><td class='col-xs-2'><span id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sampleNum" + (rowIndex + i + 1) + "'>" + specimenNumber + "</span></td></tr>";
                  $(sampleTable).append(newRow);
              }
          }
      }
```

I expect my code to replace the old row and not have extra empty table data values.

Comment: var specimenArrayLength = specimenArrayLength.filter(function (el) {return el != "";}); is a better way to get rid of empty strings than length - 1

Comment: @Evik Ghazarian  replacing it with this code did not work.